# How to solve a linear optimization problem with two arrays variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, quadratic-programming

I have two sets of $n$ 3 dimensional vectors independent from eachother ;

$$A = (f_1, f_2, ..., f_n)$$
$$C = (m_1, m_2, ..., m_n)$$

I am looking for the set of $n$ real factors, $X = (X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$, that will make the following true:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
X_1 f_1 + X_2 f_2 + ... + X_n f_n = b \\
X_1 m_1 + X_2 m_2 + ... + X_n m_n = d \\
(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n) \geq 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

i.e.:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
AX = b \\
CX = d \\
X \geq 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

I know how to obtain the optimized solution $X\geq 0$ for the individual cases of $AX = b$ or $CX = d$ using the pseudo-inverse of $A$ or $C$, $A^+$ or $C^+$ (case for $AX = b ; X \geq 0$):

$$ X = A^+b + [I-A^+A]w1 \tag{1}$$
$$ X = C^+d + [I-C^+C]w2 \tag{2}$$

Coupled with a quadratic programming solver given:

\begin{array}{ll} \underset{w}{\text{minimize}} & \frac{1}{2}w^TPw+q^Tw\\ \text{subject to} & Gw \leq h\end{array}

with (the addition of $\varepsilon*I$ in $P$ is to ensure it is definite positive):

$$P = [I - A^+A]^T[I-A^+A]+\varepsilon *I$$
$$q = -([A^+b]^T[I-A^+A])$$
$$G = -[I - A^+A]$$
$$h = [A^+b]^T$$

However, I can't figure out how to obtain both $w1$ and $w2$ so that the initial system remains true.
Depending on $A$ and $C$, a solution might not exist, I am only considering cases where at least one solution exists.

Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ allow to obtain all solutions for respectively $AX = b$ and $CX = d$, by variation of $w1$ and $w2$. In a way, I am looking for the solutions (if there are any) $X\geq 0$ that lie in the union of the solutions given by $w1$ and $w2$, if that makes any sense.

It gives me (I think?) a linear optimization problem, but with matrices and vectors instead of scalars:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
F(w1, w2) = J + Kw1 - L - Mw2 \\
Kw1 \geq -J \\
Mw2 \geq -L \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

with:

$$J = A^+b$$
$$K = [I-A^+A]$$
$$L = C^+d$$
$$M = [I-C^+C]$$

Any solution so that $F(w1, w2)$ equals $0$ would mean that a proper solution exist, I suppose.
How can I obtain the optimized solution for that program?

Comment: I am not sure to understand why you do not solve directly for $X$ such that $AX=b$, $CX=d$, and $X\ge0$?

Comment: @KBS Trying to solve for $AX = b$ and $CX = d$ while $X \geq 0$ individually would not always (in fact almost never) give the same solution $X$ for both. One would satisfy $AX = b$ and $x \geq 0$ but not $CX = d$ typically.
It's easier to see if you consider that the solution for $AX = b$ needs to take into account what C is for it to also work for $CX = d$. In a way, C imposes an additional constraint on the solution for $AX = b$ and vice-versa that you don't have by solving each individually.

Comment: Okay, then you should have mentioned this in your question. Note that if there is no such $X$, then no exact reformulation of the program will be feasible either. Then, why don't you just minimize $||MX-v||$ where $M=[A;C]$ and $v=[b;d]$?

Comment: @KBS That could work, but I don't know how to minimize that... I'm not sure what solver to use, I've only used the quadratic programming solver so far

Comment: It is a quadratic program.

Comment: @KBS Oh, of the form $\frac{1}{2}||RX-d||^2$? And subject to $[-IX \leq 0; -IX \leq 0]$ (which is just $X \geq 0$) then

Comment: Yes, that will work.

Comment: @KBS Finished the implementation in Python and it seems like it's working. I'll just leave as a note : the implementation must be done with a slight hack, since M is not always positive definite, you have to compute :
$$Q = 2M^T 2M + \varepsilon*I$$
$$c = -(2M)^T 2v$$

Comment: This can be implemented in Python using ```solve_qp(Q, c, G, h)``` from ```qpsolvers```.
$[A, C]$ can be implemented as ```M = numpy.concatenate((A, C))```.
Thank you for the useful answer!

Comment: Rather than perturbing $4M^TM$, consider using a regularization term.